# Speeding up ddply

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
n  = 50
df = data.frame(group=sample(1:as.integer(n/2),n,replace=T),
                x = runif(n),
                y = runif(n),
                z = runif(n))
df = df[with(df,order(group)),]
```

What I need to do, for each unique value of `group`, is to produce segments, ie, where new columns are produced, `xend`, `yend` and `zend`, which are the `x`, `y`, `z` values of the previous point in that group. For the last value in the group, the ends are taken as the first point in the group.

I can do this in the following manner:

```
res = ddply(df,"group",function(d){ 
  ixc  = c("x","y","z")
  dfE  = d[,ixc]
  dfE  = rbind(dfE[nrow(dfE),],dfE[1:(nrow(dfE)-1),])
  colnames(dfE) = paste0(ixc,"end")
  cbind(d,dfE)
})
print(head(res))
```

This is trivial when `n` is small, however, when `n` gets large, the time to execute the above becomes significant, is there a faster way to do this, perhaps using `data.table`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with the `shift` function from the `data.table` package. An example for `xend`:

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, xend := shift(x, 1L, fill = x[.N], type = "lag"), by = group]
```

For all columns:

```
setDT(df)[, c("xend","yend","zend") := .(shift(x, 1L, fill = x[.N], type = "lag"),
                                         shift(y, 1L, fill = y[.N], type = "lag"),
                                         shift(z, 1L, fill = z[.N], type = "lag")),
          by = group]
```

this gives you:

```
> head(df)
   group          x         y          z       xend      yend       zend
1:     1 0.56725304 0.7539735 0.20542455 0.71538606 0.3864990 0.01586889
2:     1 0.64251519 0.1255183 0.93371528 0.56725304 0.7539735 0.20542455
3:     1 0.14182485 0.7351444 0.89199415 0.64251519 0.1255183 0.93371528
4:     1 0.06613097 0.7625182 0.92669617 0.14182485 0.7351444 0.89199415
5:     1 0.71538606 0.3864990 0.01586889 0.06613097 0.7625182 0.92669617
6:     4 0.27188921 0.5496977 0.09282217 0.27188921 0.5496977 0.09282217
```

Another approach as suggested by @akrun in the comments:

```
setDT(df)[, c("xend","yend","zend") := lapply(.SD, function(x) shift(x, fill = x[.N]))
          , by = group]
```

Although this approach requires less typing and gives more flexibility with regard to including variables, it is also considerably slower.

---

In the question, you stated:

> For the last value in the group, the ends are taken as the first point
>   in the group.

However, according to the desired behavior as you described, for the last value in the group the previous value in the group is used. I supposed you mean:

> For the first value in the group, the ends are taken as the last point
>   in the group.

---

Used data:

```
set.seed(1)
n  = 1e5
df = data.frame(group=sample(1:as.integer(n/2),n,replace=T),
                x = runif(n),
                y = runif(n),
                z = runif(n))
df = df[with(df,order(group)),]
```

Comment: Which version of data.table are you using, mine is version 1.9.2, and it doesn't contain any 'shift' function.

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), , `:=`(xend, shift(x, 1L, fill = x[.N],  : 
  could not find function "shift"

Comment: @NicholasHamilton See also my comment about the last/first value. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I think for multiple columns `setDT(df)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) shift(x, fill=x[.N])), group]` , where `nm1 <-  paste0(names(df)[-1], 'end')`

Comment: @akrun Thanx! Added it to my answer :-) (unfortunately it is much slower though: approximately 2x)

Comment: @Jaap I didn't check the timings.  Thanks for letting me know that it is slow